# Setting Discriminator value at registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I'm trying to figure out how to go about setting the `Discriminator` value for a user during the registration process. Here's the code I have auto generated by Visual Studio:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email };
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        AddErrors(result);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly where or how I'm supposed to specify the `Discriminator` here, as most of the workings seem to be abstracted through `UserManager.CreateAsync`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set the discriminator - EF will set the appropriate discriminator value based on the type of the object derived from `IdentityUser` (in this case, `ApplicationUser`).

Comment: So it's just pulled directly from the class name? Would manually creating another `IdentityUser` derived class be a reasonable way to go about differentiating user types, or is there some cleaner way I'm not aware of?

Comment: Another type derived from `IdentityUser` would have a different discriminator value if mapped to the same table.  What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to, well, discriminate users by type. e.g. regular users/customers, suppliers, admins. It's a retail website if that helps.

Comment: Derive your user types from `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: Ok, I've sort of moved on at the moment, but I'll give that a shot when I get back around to it, thanks. Will be sure to mark as accepted if all goes fine.

Comment: @Moho For me it doesn't pull the discriminator from the derived class, which is in my case 'User'